# How to add predefines to the .cproject file after running a Build Target

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, waf

I'm trying to import a C project to eclipse (CDT) that is managed by waf. There is a list of predefines generated by waf (when running `./waf configure`). That list has to be imported to `Project->Properties->C/C++ General/Paths and Symbols/Symbols/GNU C` so that the indexer knows about them and does not print errors. That list (when using the GUI) is stored to the `.cproject` file. I created a Build Target that runs `./waf configure` and stores the list to a file named `DEFINES.txt`. How do I automatically update the list of `.cproject` with the values of `DEFINES.txt` after running the Build Target?

I thought about the following solutions and their follow-up problems:

1. Solution: Writing a plug-in.
   Problem: What is the appropriate extension point?
2. Solution: Writing an external program that calls `./waf configure` reads `DEFINES.txt` and writes the list to `.cproject`. That program replaces the old Build Target.
   Problem: How safe is this? Am I allowed to change the `.cproject` file by an external program without causing any problems?
3. Solution: Implementing the `.cproject` updating algorithm in `wscript` file.
   Problem: This is not a solution for me, because the project is used by others, too, that do not use eclipse as IDE. So the modified `wscript` will cause errors if the other developers want to build the project.

Does anybody have better ideas or some advice?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to go about it:

1. Writing a plug-in: What I recommend you do is write an extension to the [LanguageSettingsProvider](http://git.eclipse.org/c/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt.git/tree/core/org.eclipse.cdt.core/schema/LanguageSettingsProvider.exsd). The [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/Developer/FAQ#How_do_I_contribute_Include.2FLibrary_paths_or_Macros_to_a_project_configuration_using_LanguageSettingsProvider_extension_point.3F) has some more info, but the summary is that provider does:

> This extension point is used to contribute a new Language Settings
>   Provider. A Language Settings Provider is used to get additions to
>   compiler options such as include paths (-I) or preprocessor defines
>   (-D) and others into the project model.

2. CMake has an option to generate .cproject as part of its configure state, so you could do something similar. See the [CMake Wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) for inspiration, but the summary is that you don't store and .cproject/.project in source control and have CMake (or waf in your case) generate the IDE specific files.
3. You could also just pick up the build settings using the build output parser and ignore the DEFINES.txt altogether. That requires running the build once from within Eclipse for CDT to see all the commands, and requires the commands to be parseable in the build output.